# iOS - searching a table view which is populated by an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, xcode, dictionary, plist, uisearchbar

I have a plist file that is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has 5 similar keys and the tableview displays the title key. Eventually i will have 136 + titles so i want to implement a search function so to find desired information quickly.

I am using the nspredicate to search the title and it works. The searched result reloads a new table display the searched results. The problem I am having is when a user selects a searched title, the detail view doesn't display the correct information in that dictionary.

I know logically why it doesn't work, but cannot figure out how to fix it.

Thanks

*edit*

Code for didSelect:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = nil;
        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {

```
        id searchResult = [searchResultsTitle objectAtIndex:1];

        indexPath1 = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = [searchResultsTitle valueForKeyPath:@"description"];
               }
    else {

    self.detailViewController.detailItem = decsText;
    self.detailViewController.title = selectedTitle;
```

}
}

So When the search is active, the titles are displayed, but I want the search selected title to open up the appropriate detail referred to as 'description'

Comment: Could to show code snippet of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Any one help? Really struggling!!